# Widget not work in iOS 17 Please adopt containerBackground API

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget, ios17

When developing widgets for iOS 17, I encountered a problem that the widgets did not work. The preview shows only the error - containerBackground API
I read similar articles on this matter, and they say that you need to use

```
extension View {
func widgetBackground(_ backgroundView: some View) -> some View {
       if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *) {
           return containerBackground(for: .widget) {
               backgroundView
           }
       } else {
           return background(backgroundView)
       }
   }
```

but it doesn't work for me

I have a simple widget that shows the time. I will provide the code below

```
struct TimeWidgetEntryView: View {
var entry: TimeWidgetProvider.Entry

var body: some View {
    if let clock = UserDefaultStorage.shared.standByClockValue,
       case .single(let model) = clock.blockType {
        ZStack {
            Image(clock.imageName ?? "texture - 1")
               
            Text(DateFormatter.hourAndMinute.string(from: entry.date))
                .font(.custom(model.font.fontName, size: 50))
                .foregroundColor(Color(model.textColor))
            if !UserDefaultStorage.shared.hasPremiumStatus, UserDefaultStorage.shared.isLastTryTime {
                PremiumView()
            }
        } .widgetBackground(Color.black)
    } else {
        if !UserDefaultStorage.shared.hasPremiumStatus {
            ZStack {
                WidgetEmptyView()
                    .widgetBackground(Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
struct WidgetEmptyView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("texture - 1")
                .scaledToFill()
            Color.black
            VStack {
                Image("Frame 11114563")
                    .resizable()
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                Text("Select your clock")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 150)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .font(.custom("Gilroy-Bold", size: 20))
                    .dynamicTypeSize(.medium)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```